# How to add Secure URL for Custom rewrite URL In Magento custom Module

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Am trying to add secure URL to my custom module - below is my config.xml sample code

```
     <frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <scheme>/scheme/</scheme>
        </secure_url>
        <routers>
            <scheme>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Companyname_Scheme</module>
                    <frontName>scheme</frontName>
                </args>
            </scheme>
        </routers> 
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <rewrite>            
            <myschemes>
                <from><![CDATA[/myschemes\/(.*)/]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[scheme/user/$1/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </myschemes>
        </rewrite>
   </global>
```

My need is to make **myschemes** url to access only through https:// (eg: https://www.example.com/myschemes/) if the user forced to load on non http i.e., http://www.example.com/myschemes/ .

If i add secure url for **myschemes** then above rewrite is not working. If i enter https://www.example.com/myschemes/ as url it is redirecting to https://www.example.com/scheme/user//

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got this sample *config.xml* from an old Magento or and old Magento tutorial ([like this ?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210413052026/http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/29/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml/)) since those kind of rewrite of controller routes are not used anymore.

But for further comprehension here is what your actual code does:

```xml
<from><![CDATA[/myschemes\/(.*)/]]></from>
```

This line is a *'.htaccess like'* mechanism in Magento, the group `(.*)` tells Magento to get everything after `myschemes/` and the following `/` for further processing

```xml
<to><![CDATA[scheme/user/$1/]]></to>
```

And this tells Magento to get the info of the `(.*)` and append that to `scheme/user/`

So, if you write http://www.example.com/myschemes/some_info_or_id/ Magento is going to redirect you to http://www.example.com/scheme/user/some_info_or_id.
As a matter of fact this `(.*)` and `$1` mechanism is a dynamic redirect when you do have parameters in your query URL.

Now, I don't think this would help or relate to your original question, but, that is what your code does right now.

What you want to achieve can be done by this *config.xml*:

```xml
<frontend>
    <!-- there under is the xml node you need -->
    <secure_url>
        <scheme>/myschemes</scheme>
    </secure_url>
    <routers>
        <scheme>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Companyname_Scheme</module>
                <frontName>myschemes</frontName>
            </args>
        </scheme>
    </routers> 
</frontend>
<!-- global>
    <rewrite>            
        <myschemes>
            <from><![CDATA[/myschemes\/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[scheme/user/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </myschemes>
    </rewrite>
</global -->
```

Please note, the `<scheme>` node under `<secure_url>` is an handle, you may rename it as you best like.
Please also note that you can even refine the https protection to only one controller of your module like this:

```xml
<secure_url>
    <scheme>/myschemes/controllername</scheme>
</secure_url>
```

Or even to a single action like this

```xml
<secure_url>
    <scheme>/myschemes/controllername/actionname</scheme>
</secure_url>
```

For further reference please have a look at some of the core modules like the *config.xml* of `Mage_Rss` or of `Mage_Checkout`.